# How To Limit Column Values Retrieved From Another Column

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I am trying to get a column in Google Sheets to display the values produced by another column but if they are greater than 10, I want it to just display 10 for that cell but if the cell would contain a number less than 10 that cell within the column still contains the original value.

I tried a query with an IF statement but I'll admit I'm too sure how this works

```
=query(D:D,"select D label D 'Your total points'" & IF("D">10,10,"D"),1)
```

I expected a new column to list all the values in column D unless they were greater than 10. If they were greater than 10, I expected the cell to contain the value 10 instead of the original value of the corresponding cell in column D.

Instead I get the following error:

> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered "  "10 "" at line 1, column 37. Was expecting one of:  "format" ... "options" ... "," ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Your total points"; IF(D2:D>10, 10, D2:D)})
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Your total points"; IFERROR(IF(D2:D*1<10, D2:D, 10), D2:D)})
```

[image]